# Trying to search table in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, sql

I am trying to create a search within my table.

I have the table populated with date already loaded, but when i type into the search box for example a name and press submit, nothing is happening the page just reloads and nothing happens.

Here is the code, (i also need to do the same with a table where the table data is all foreign keys.)

```
    <?php // Include config file
include("$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/freddies/inc/config.php");
include("$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/freddies/inc/functions.php");
include("$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/freddies/inc/header.php");

  $sql = "SELECT * FROM patient";

if (isset($_POST['searchform'])) {

  $search_term = ($_POST['searchpat']);

  $sql .= " WHERE fName LIKE '{$search_term}'";
  $sql .= " OR sName LIKE '{$search_term}'";
  $sql .= " OR addLineOne LIKE '{$search_term}'";
}

$query = mysqli_query($db, $sql) or die(mysql_error());

?>

<body>
<div class="container">
<?php include("$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/freddies/inc/logo.html"); ?>

  <h2>List of Patients</h2>
  <p>All Patients Registered with Freddies Medical:</p>     

  <form name="searchform" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Search for Patient</label>
                            <input type="text"  class="form-control" name="searchpat" required><br>
                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="search" value="Submit">
                            <span class="help-block"></span>
                        </div>

  <table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Surname</th>
        <th>Address</th>
        <th>Phone</th>
        <th>Email Address</th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php
        $no     = 1;
        $total  = 0;
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
        {
            echo '<tr>
                    <td>'.$row['fName'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row['sName'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row['addLineOne'].", ".$row['addCity'].", ".$row['addPostCode'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row['phone'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row['email'].'</td>
                    <td><a href="patprofile.php?id='.($row['patient_id']).'" class="btn btn-success pull-right btn-xs">View Patient</a></td>   
                    <td><a href="delpat.php?id='.($row['patient_id']).'" class="btn btn-danger pull-right btn-xs">Delete</a></td>
                        </tr>';    
            $no++;
        }?>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <a href="createpatient.php" class="btn btn-success pull-left">New Patient</a>
  <a href="../" class="btn btn-info pull-right">Admin Area</a>
</div>
<div class="bottompadding"></div>
<?php include("$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/freddies/inc/footer.php"); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You forgot the `$` in the front of `search_term`.

Comment: Your script is at risk of [SQL Injection Attack](//stackoverflow.com/questions/60174) Have a look at what happened to [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](//stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187) Use [prepared parameterized statements](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: you also have a naming conflict.

Comment: then there's the form's naming with the conditional. That only works with JS, which you tagged with but didn't show us that bit.

Comment: thanks for the heads up @JohnConde this is just for a Uni assignment and wont be real world. they havent really taught us much to be fair and i have an assignement to hand in today :/

Comment: I have updated the code. renamed search to searchpat and added $ before search_term but it is still not working

Comment: `mysql_error()` doesn't work with the mysqli_ api. Best thing is use php's error reporting and the correct method for error handling on mysql. Good luck, I have to make London in 2 hours.

Comment: `$_POST['searchform']` will not be set as for as I know. Better check `isset($_POST['search'])`.

Comment: Legend @Brainfeeder i had isset searchform rather than search.. thanks bud.

Although, how do i have it so it lists all the information, but when i type in search and press submit it brings back searched term

Comment: It should work as you have it, only when the form is posted the query for db will have extra statements. I updated my answer a little. Just keep in mind what @JohnConde said using this code.

Comment: thansk for the help guys.. really appreciate it.. 

if i was to use the same code but change the input search to a select option populated by a table in the db, how would i filter the data using the selected option.

;

Comment: the data in the html table will be from a table conisisting of the following $sql  = "SELECT patient.fName AS fname, patient.sName AS surname, doctor.sName AS doc, conditions.con_name AS con, drugs.medication AS meds, visit.visitdate, visit.visit_id AS visitid  FROM visit 
            JOIN patient ON visit.patient_id = patient.patient_id
            JOIN doctor ON visit.doctor_id = doctor.doctor_id
            LEFT JOIN conditions ON visit.con_id = conditions.con_id
            LEFT JOIN drugs ON visit.drugs_id = drugs.med_id
            ORDER BY visitdate ASC"

Comment: thanks very much @Brainfeeder you have helped tremendously.

Comment: If you have another question that is different from this one, please submit a new question so you can post relevant code there instead of in comments. :)

Comment: The link relating to the above question. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50101891/searching-for-data-within-joined-tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$_POST['searchform']` will not be set as far as I know since it is the name of the form and not a form element. Better check for `isset($_POST['search'])`:

```
if(isset($_POST['search'])) {
    $search_term = $_POST['searchpat'];

    $sql .= " WHERE fName LIKE '%".$search_term."%'"; // Using % wildcard will search for fields 'containing' searched string rather then 'exact matches'
    $sql .= " OR sName LIKE '%".$search_term."%'";
    $sql .= " OR addLineOne LIKE '%".$search_term."%'";
}
```